# Allow IFileOpenDialog to pick a file that is not created yet

Tags: c++, winapi, openfiledialog

I have seen this in many applications. You get the option to open a file and if it does not exists, it is created and you don't get any complain. All from the same *Open File* dialog. 
I use `IFileOpenDialog` to open a file and if I input a file that does not exists, it shows me an error and I cannot get the path to this file.

What I want is not to get an error but have the non existing file name accepted. Later I will create it. Is this possible?

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

    // Create the FileOpenDialog object
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_FileOpenDialog,
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_ALL, 
        IID_IFileOpenDialog, 
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen)
    );

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Show the Open dialog box.
        hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

        // Get the file name from the dialog box.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IShellItem *pItem;
            hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PWSTR pszFilePath;
                hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                // Check if file actually exists
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Create file if not found
                    if (PathFileExists(pszFilePath) != 1)
                    {

                    }

                    CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                }
                pItem->Release();
            }
        }
        pFileOpen->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`call IFileDialog::GetOptions` to get the default options, remove FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST and FOS_FILEMUSTEXIST bits, then set the new options back with `IFileDialog::SetOptions`.